# Retrieve keywords from MySQL full-text search

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

MySQL full-text search from a query string entered by a user: How can I retrieve the keywords ([boolean mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)) in an array-like format so I can use them for hit-highlighting? Or do I have to reinvent everything in PHP to figure out which keywords from the query string MySQL used for the search?

Comment: Where do the keywords come from?  What is "hit-highlighting"?  "Array-like" sounds like `GROUP_CONCAT()`, but that needs single words, not long text.  Reinvent what?

Comment: @RickJames Hit-highlighting means marking the search keywords in the results (like Google). MySQL full-text searches a database by a query _string_, including boolean operators, quotes etc. What I want is to get an array containing the individual keywords, without special characters. If MySQL can do this, I don't have to invent my own query string parser to extract "possible" keywords.

Comment: MySQL can search by regexp, but cannot substitute what it finds. Plan on using MySQL as a repository for text and PHP for most of the processing.